# Controlling zindex on leaflet icons layer

Tags: leaflet

In below I am trying to bring the green circle to the front by clicking the button. How can I achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ccsdf()">Click me</button>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 90vh"></div>

<script>
    var map;
    var layer1;
    var layer2;

    function ccsdf() {
        layer1.bringToFront();    
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 14);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        layer1 = L.geoJson({ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 0.0005 ]}}]}, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.icon({ iconUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Small_red_circle.png' }) });
            }
        }).addTo(map);

        layer2 = L.geoJson({ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 0 ]}}]}, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.icon({ iconUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Blue_1.png' }) });
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Below text is because stack overflow wants me to write more :-)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, interdum est eu. A tellus condimentum hendrerit enim, ligula fusce vitae, leo et fusce mauris lorem suscipit scelerisque. Vel arcu, non vestibulum suspendisse non lectus magnis suspendisse, aliquam magna commodo. Nascetur eleifend at faucibus faucibus, nulla fringilla, mauris ultrices posuere in

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zevicogudi/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly why [`featureGroup.bringToFront()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-bringtofront) does not seem to work in your case. It may be that it works only on vector shapes, which do have individual [`bringToFront()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtofront) as well, on the contrary of markers.

Anyway, you can simply use [`layerGroup.eachLayer()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) to apply a [`zIndexOffset`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-zindexoffset) to each marker (you may need to check if the layer is an `L.Marker` if your group has many layers). You can simply use the [`marker.setZIndexOffset()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setzindexoffset) to achieve this.

```js
function ccsdf() {
    //layer1.bringToFront();   
    layer1.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      layer.setZIndexOffset(1000);
    });
}
```

Demo on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lQLNiR5HwX4vT84vBLAC?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

This plugin will do the trick: [leaflet.forceZIndex.js](https://gist.github.com/up209d/4c68f2391f2302e510eb81aa8bcd4514)

```
// Force zIndex of Leaflet
(function(global){
  var MarkerMixin = {
    _updateZIndex: function (offset) {
      this._icon.style.zIndex = this.options.forceZIndex ? (this.options.forceZIndex + (this.options.zIndexOffset || 0)) : (this._zIndex + offset);
    },
    setForceZIndex: function(forceZIndex) {
      this.options.forceZIndex = forceZIndex ? forceZIndex : null;
    }
  };
  if (global) global.include(MarkerMixin);
})(L.Marker);
```

To use:

```
var aMarker = L.marker([lat, lon], {
    icon: icon,
    title: title,
    forceZIndex: <Value> // This is forceZIndex value
})
```

forceZIndex declaration will assure that ZIndex will be always set from aMarker.options.forceZIndex

Update it somewhere to re-force ZIndex value

```
aMarker.setForceZIndex(<New Value>)
```

Or setForceZIndex(null) to automatical zIndex state:

```
aMarker.setForceZIndex(null);
```

By the end of the day, if no forceZIndex option declared, Marker will work with normal behaviour.